# DateTimePicker Choose records between dates

Tags: mysql, vb.net

My question is about searching in vbnet with mysql between two dates that are selected in datetimepicker.I have searched it in many forums but unfortunately no luck

```vb
Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
Dim bsource As New BindingSource
Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        ' MessageBox.Show("ok")
        Dim query As String
        query = "SELECT * FROM(patient)  WHERE imerominia BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker3.Text & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker4.Text & "'  group BY imerominia"

        command = New MySqlCommand(query, mysqlconn)
        sda.SelectCommand = command
        sda.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        sda.Update(dbdataset)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While reader.Read
            Dim imerominia As String = reader.GetString("imerominia")
            Dim imerominia1 As String = reader.GetString("imerominia")
            DateTimePicker3.Text = (imerominia)
            DateTimePicker4.Text = (imerominia1)

        End While
        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim dbdataset As New DataTable
Dim bsource As New BindingSource
Dim sda As New MySqlDataAdapter
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        mysqlconn.Open()
        ' MessageBox.Show("ok")
        'Dim query As String
        'query = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE imerominia BETWEEN '" & DateTimePicker3.Text & "' AND '" & DateTimePicker4.Text & "'  group BY imerominia"

        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();

        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM patient WHERE imerominia BETWEEN '" & @p_Date & "' AND '" & @p1_Date & "'  group BY imerominia"
        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@p_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker3.Value;
        cmd.Parameters.Add ("@p1_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = DateTimePicker4.Value;


        sda.SelectCommand = cmd
        sda.Fill(dbdataset)
        bsource.DataSource = dbdataset
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bsource
        sda.Update(dbdataset)
        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader

        While reader.Read
            Dim imerominia As String = reader.GetString("imerominia")
            Dim imerominia1 As String = reader.GetString("imerominia")
            DateTimePicker3.Text = (imerominia)
            DateTimePicker4.Text = (imerominia1)

        End While
        mysqlconn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        mysqlconn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

`DateTimePicker3.Text` should not be used instead you can use `DateTimePicker3.Value.Date`. `DateTimePicker.Value` is the DateTime represented by the control. `DateTimePicker.Text` is HOW the control shows its date to the user according to the `Format` property

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it says expression needed at symbol @...using visual studio 2010 vbnet